# Setting the mstatus register for RISC-V

Tags: riscv

I am trying to load mstatus with another register t1.

```
 lw t1, mstatus              # load mstatys register into t1
 xori t1, t1, 0x8            # xor mstatus to set 3rd bit and leave everything else as is
 lw mstatus, t1              # set mstatus
```

The initial `lw t1, mstatus` works just fine. However when trying to `lw mstatus, t1` the assembler gives

```
Error: illegal operands 'lw mstatus, t1'
```

I have no idea what causes this error, mstatus register is a read/write register. It should work.

Comment: addi mstatus, t1, 0 brings the same error

Comment: try `sw t1, mstatus`

Comment: Are you trying to _set_ 3rd bit (as the comment says), or to _toggle_ it? Because `ori` would be the correct instruction for setting (`xori` would be for toggling, so its use is inconsistent with the comment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mstatus` is not a memory part. Then it can't be loaded/stored with lw/sw instructions under general purpose registers (x1-x31).

`mstatus` is part of CSR (Control Status Registers) that been accessed with Control and Status Register Instruction (see chapter 2.8 of [riscv-spec](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf)).

Then to load `mstatus` you should use csrrs/c instruction and to write csrrw instruction depending of what you want to do you can also just clear/set individual bit of register.

Write t1 in `mstatus` and don't care of `mstatus` old value (x0):

> csrrw t1, mstatus, x0

Read mstatus in t1 and don't touch mstatus value:

> csrrs x0, mstatus, t1

or

> csrrc x0, mstatus, t1

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @FabienM‘s answer, I would add a reference to the pseudo instructions for handling CSRs. E.g. `csrr rd, csr` which is short for `csrrs rd, csr, x0` and simply reads the given CSR. Those can be found in chapter 9.1 "CSR Instructions", of the [The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume I: Unprivileged ISA](https://riscv.org/specifications/).